# Animate chars added to a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to add an effect when a new char is added to the #messageCorrectrlyTyped span? So when the user type the right char? I try setting `transition: all 1s;`into the css but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

```js
var messageToType = document.querySelector("#messageToType");
var messageCorrectlyTyped = document.querySelector("#messageCorrectlyTyped");
var correctlyTyped = "";

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 if (messageToType.textContent.length > 0) {
  var charToPress = messageToType.textContent[0];
  var charPressed = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (charPressed === charToPress) {
   messageToType.textContent = messageToType.textContent.substring(1);
   messageCorrectlyTyped.textContent += charPressed;
   messageCorrectlyTyped.style.color = "green";
  } 
 }
});
```

```css
#messageToType {
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#messageCorrectlyTyped {
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#container {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test Type</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testType.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <span id="messageCorrectlyTyped"></span><span id="messageToType">ciao</span>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="testType.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot animate your char if you concatenate to an existing string, the whole string can be animated, not adding a char. You need either to create a different element with your char only to animate it, or use another element upon your text that animates the display. By the way, support of `e.keyCode` is limited and won't work in all browsers (see `e.which`)

Comment: @Kaddath what do you mean with "use another element upon your text that animates the display"?

Comment: actually trichetriche's answer shows this perfectly: the string is fixed and has no animation, and he uses a hiding element to reveal the chars (this trick will work when your animation doesn't require your char to move)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide question.

Here is an example, tell me if it works for you :

```js
const hider = document.querySelector('.hider');

const width = hider.offsetWidth;
hider.style.left = '0px';

const inter = setInterval(() => {
  let left = +hider.style.left.replace('px', '');
  if(left <= width) {
    hider.style.left = (left + 1) + 'px';
  } else { clearInterval(inter); }
}, 5);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.hider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-right: -1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 4%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</div>
  <div class="hider"></div>
</div>
```